# Trying to load .npy file in "write" mode corrupts the file

Tags: python, numpy

When loading a .npy file, I sometimes accidentally open the file in "write" mode instead of "read" mode (usually after copy-pasting). However this seems to corrupt the file, and the .npy file can't be loaded even after changing to "read" mode. Why does this happen? And is there a way to recover the .npy file?

Here's a MWE:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 1])

# save data:
with open('tmp.npy', 'wb') as f:
    np.save(f, a)

try:
    # accidentally try to load .npy in write mode:
    with open('tmp.npy', 'wb') as f:
        a = np.load(f)
except:
    # fix typo and open in read mode:
    with open('tmp.npy', 'rb') as f:
        a = np.load(f)                       # raises "ValueError: Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False"
        # a = np.load(f, allow_pickle=True)  # raises "OSError: Failed to interpret file <_io.BufferedReader name='tmp.npy'> as a pickle"
```

Loading the file raises the error: `ValueError: Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False`. Setting `allow_pickle=True`, but this gives an `OSError`.

I'm using `with open()` both for saving and loading following the [official documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html), however I'm not sure if this is necessary.

I'm using Python 3.7, and numpy 1.21.

Comment: I'm not sure you should be doing `open('tmp.npy', 'wb')` at all. You can instead directly use `np.load('tmp.npy')`
same goes while saving, just say `np.save('tmp.npy', a)`

Comment: Opening any file in write mode creates a new file with that name, replacing the existing.  There is an append mode that allows write without destroying the original.  But unless you are trying to do something 'dangerous' I don't see why you need the separate `open`.

Comment: After you get that write open error, check the size of  the file. My gurss it will be smaller, even 0 bytes.

Comment: I followed the [official documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html), they use `with open()` both to save and load .npy files.